# JavaScript to find whether any div with a particular class was hovered over and then identify the exact div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here is my HTML:

```html
<div id="doc1" class="document-container-title">
    <h3>Doc 1</h3>
</div>
<div id="doc2" class="document-container-title">
    <h3>Doc 2</h3>
</div>
<div id="doc3" class="document-container-title">
    <h3>Doc 3</h3>
</div>
```

As you can see, each `div` has a class of 'document-container-title'. I want to add some JavaScript to detect if any one of these `divs` were hovered over, and then I want to find out which specific div was hovered over. Specifically, I want to be able to detect whether a div with the class of `document-container-title` was hovered over. If so, then I want to get the id of the exact div that was hovered over.

I am only one month into JavaScript so a helpful explanation wouldn't hurt.

Thanks.

P.S. I don't mind using jQuery.

Comment: Use [event delegation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation). E.g., use an [event argument](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback)’s [`target`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Event/target). See [the tag info](/tags/event-delegation/info) and [What is DOM Event delegation?](/q/1687296/4642212).

Comment: Do you want the last hovered div only? Or a list of all divs where the mouse has been over?

Comment: Wow! I didn't even though this was possible through JavaScript. Event delegation rocks, and so do you! Thanks @SebastianSimon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jQuery `mouseover` or `mouseenter` event  based on your requirement like this:

Based on [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery):

> The **mouseover** event triggers when the mouse pointer enters the div
> element, and its child elements.

However

> The **mouseenter** event is only triggered when the mouse pointer enters
> the div element.

```js
$(".document-container-title").mouseover(function (e) {
     console.log(e.currentTarget.textContent);
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="doc1" class="document-container-title">
        <h3>Doc 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="doc2" class="document-container-title">
        <h3>Doc 2</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="doc3" class="document-container-title">
        <h3>Doc 3</h3>
    </div>
```

Comment: Two questions: Why `Event.target` instead of `Event.currentTarget` and why `"mouseover"`? Don't use `Event.target` unless you really, really know what you're doing. Also learn about the difference about mouseover and mouseenter.

Comment: This worked exactly how I wanted it to. Thanks - the code explained itself!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan For the first part I got you and I updated my answer. but for the second part you are saying that `mouseover` does not satisfy OP's problem?

Comment: _"but with jQuery has a clean way to do that"_ - A non-jQuery version isn't that different: `document.querySelectorAll(".document-container-title").forEach((el) => el.addEventListener("mouseover", (ev) => console.log(ev.currentTarget.id)))`

Comment: @Andreas I know that but there is no need to create loop even with JavaScript. we can use event deligation

Comment: _"we can use event deligation"_ - Your answer doesn't use event delegation o.O

Comment: @Andreas I'm saying that with pure JavaScript :). sorry my poor English. But you are right my answer does not use event delegation. I said `Clean` because of few lines of code :)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is this one:

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('document-container-title')
for (let element of elements) {
    element.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.id);
    });
}
```

First, you will iterate over your DOM to get all elements with the specified class. The defined constant `elements` is now an array of html elements that have the `document-container-title` class. After that, you will have a simple for loop to iterate over all gathered elements. Finally, you will add an event listener for the current element in the for loop that will trigger the `mouseenter` event. Then, you can easily get the [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) with their corresponding id.

[Reproduction link](https://jsfiddle.net/kzrxetba/)